# Heroku Deploy failing to install NPM packages

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku

I am trying to deploy a node.js app to Heroku through the web interface, connecting the git repo.
Facing the below error during deployment. It's not able to install dependencies.

**Heroku Error Log:
**

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  12.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.22.12...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.16
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! Cannot read property 'aws-sdk' of undefined
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.XadcE/_logs/2024-03-10T17_02_48_371Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

**package.json
**

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.x"
  },
  "description": "Backend APIs for Customer microservice",
  "main": "server.js",
  "bin": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
    "start:prod": "node server.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "pkg": {
    "scripts": "build/**/*.js",
    "assets": [
      "controllers/**/*",
      "database/**/*",
      "functions/*",
      "node_modules/**.*",
      "routes/**/*"
    ],
    "targets": [
      "node12-macos-x64",
      "node12-win-x64",
      "node12-linux-x64"
    ],
    "outputPath": "build"
  },
  "author": "xxxxx",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1381.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "csv-parser": "^3.0.0",
    "csvtojson": "^2.0.10",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sequelize": "^6.15.1",
    "twilio": "^3.84.1",
    "@vonage/server-sdk": "^3.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```

My other heroku deployments have had very similar package.json.
Any idea what could be wrong here?

1. Deleted package-lock.json & node_modules
2. Ran `npm i` locally and committed the new package-lock.json
3. Started up the app locally and ensured it works

Comment: A good starting point might be not using Node 12/npm 6.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider updating node version. This error might be due to the compatibility issues.
As per heroku documentation:

> Heroku supports the Current version of Node.js and all Active
> Long-Term-Support (LTS) versions. Heroku supports new releases within
> 24 hours of the official release from the Node team. As the Node.js
> release schedule illustrates, Heroku currently supports Node.js
> versions 18.x and 20.x.

You can find more details in this heroku article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support